# Finding historical data for indices

Tags: data, market-data, index, basket

Where can I find historical data for option prices on a given index ? Ideally I'd like to find for a period of several months
1) historical prices on options on a given index
2) historical prices on options on the components of this index

Potential for an index that doesn't have too many components

Is there a website where this data is easily available ? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[CBOE](https://www.cboe.com/DelayedQuote/QuoteTable.aspx) has something with limited capacity.

[Yahoo Finance](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/op?s=MSFT%20Options) also gives the current option chain.

But historical option data is not free. The most affordable I saw is [here](https://www.historicaloptiondata.com/). I don't know about its validity but their structure seems good and almost clean. More importantly, data seems reliable.

p.s. I am not sure if providing the paid data link is within T&C of this site (if it is please immediately delete this post). But, as an academic studying on options, I am sharing the link mainly because finding affordable and quality data on options is almost impossible even for research purposes.

Comment: @berkobay, it's either affordable or quality :). As an academic, you can check if your university is subscribed to OptionMetrics.

Comment: @Eli Let's say it is good quality for the price :) I did and I even tried for our university to purchase it. But I think to justify the cost, (many) more researchers are required.

Comment: Absolutely agreed. I don't know how many Ph.D. students there are in your institution, but it definitely takes a few in the department to justify the purchase.

Just as a nice resource, here is the collection of interesting papers:

http://www.optionmetrics.com/research.html